# How does the Python runtime know which object a method is bound to?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When defining methods in a class we do have an argument for the object on which the method is invoked i.e *self*.

Say I have a class `Foo`, and an instance of it:

```py
class Foo:
   def m(self):
       pass

foo = Foo()
```

and we do something like this:

```py
foo_m = foo.m
```

and then try calling `foo_m` with the same parameters the way would have done with `foo.m`. It just works.

So how does `foo_m` knows what should be the value of the self argument when it is not being called in `foo.m()` fashion?

When printing the `foo.m`, the REPL shows that its a `bound method` to that particular object.

Is it some other function object that keeps track of the `self` argument and the method to be called?

Comment: `foo_m` is bound to `foo.m` and therefor also to the `foo`object, when it is called it internally uses `foo` as the self parameter.

Comment: You can think of it like a `functools.partial`, where `self` is already set to the instance and you just supply the *other* parameters.

Comment: Isn't foo_m just s reference to the original object?

Answer (score 4):

A *bound method* is just a Python object that stores `self` in one of its slots. Take a look at [`methodobject.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/methodobject.c) for the C implementation. In Python the slot is accessible via the [`__self__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-36) attribute:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3].append
>>> a
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103b39588>
>>> a.__self__
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors) (the same that underlies `@property`).

Very simply*, if you do `foo.m`, it works roughly like calling `getattribute(foo, 'm')` in the following pseudocode:

```
def getattribute(obj, attr):
    if attr in obj.__dict__:
        # instance variable
        return obj.__dict__[attr]

    # class variable
    for cls in type(obj).__mro__:
        # MRO: method resolution order, sequence of the type and all its superclasses
        if attr in cls.__dict___:
            value = cls.__dict__[attr]
            break
        else:  # no break
            raise AttributeError(attr)

    if hasattr(value, '__get__'):
        # descriptor protocol gets invoked!
        return value.__get__(obj, type(obj))

    # regular class variable
    return value
```

* This is only valid if `obj` is not a type, and if there is no  `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__` involved, but I'm ignoring those possibilities because they complicate the story but aren't very relevant for your particular question.

Additionally, any occurrence of attribute access inside of `getattribute` is actually not regular attribute access, so there's no infinite regression.

Methods work because all Python functions are descriptors themselves, and they work a bit like this:

```
class FunctionType:
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ... # don't think about this one too hard
    def __get__(self, instance, class_):
        if instance is None:  # Foo.m
            return self
        return BoundFunction(__func__=self, __self__=instance) # foo.m

@dataclass
class BoundFunction:
    __func__: FunctionType
    __self__: Any
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # because self.__func__ is an instance variable, it doesn't invoke the descriptor protocol!
        return self.__func__(self.__self__, *args, **kwargs)
```